# How to validate text size in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I want to validate text size (not file size) in laravel how can i do this?

for example i have a long text and i want to validate text <100KB, i search it up but can't find the answer, most the answer suggest me using max:100 * 1024 but it only validate max character not the binary size, when i have 150KB text i still can upload it and its wrong. any solution?

Here is my code:

```
        $maxSizeByte = Constant::MAX_FILE_SIZE * 1024;

        $rules = [
            "id_submission" => "required|numeric",
            "text" => "required",
            "text.*" => "required|max:$maxSizeByte",
        ];
```

Comment: why such requirement? any specific use case?

Comment: closed just when I was about to post an answer.

Comment: You could use a custom rule to validate the text using `strlen` to get the string's size in bytes. `$rules = ['text' => ['required', 'string', function (string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail) { $max_bytes = 1024 * 150; if ( strlen($value) > $max_bytes ) { $fail("$attribute can not be more than $max_bytes bytes"); } }];`

Comment: Instead of `strlen` use `mb_strlen`

Comment: Why are you using `text.*` instead of `'text' => "required|max:$maxSizeByte"`?